# is there any api that can give me a shortest path given multiple locations?

Tags: optimization, routes, maps

is there any api that provide a service where I can give multiple locations and return me a shortest route for them ? if anyone know if google maps have that service and can point it out to me please

i didn't find what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The Google Directions API will do the job for you. It supports multipart directions using a series of waypoints. You will have to request for an API key first, and note that it is not a free service. A try mode (free) is available though.

Here are a few links to get you started [Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview), [Pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing)